# Public Function only works when called from the initial view controller and not after segue

Tags: ios, swift

For my own learning, I am trying to adapt a sample playground project about parsing json to an Xcode project, but I have run into a problem that I think is revealing that there is something I am seriously not understanding.

I have a public class called DataManager. In that class is this function:

```
    public class func getTopAppsFromItunesNativeParse(completion: @escaping (_ appsFromItunes: [String]) ->())  {

    var appsFromItunes = [String]()

     let session = URLSession.shared

    let topAppURLFromString = URL(string: DataManager.topAppURL)


    let loadDataTask = session.dataTask(with: topAppURLFromString!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let responseError = error {


        } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

            if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {


            } else {


                var json: Payload!

                // 1
                do {
                    json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? Payload
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                // 2
                guard let feed = json["feed"] as? Payload,
                    let apps = feed["entry"] as? [AnyObject]
                    else { print("sorry brah");return }

                // 3
                for topApp in apps {

                    guard let container = topApp["im:name"] as? Payload,
                        let appName = container["label"] as? String
                        else{print("bummer");return }

                    appsFromItunes.append(appName)

                }


            }
        }
    }


    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()

        loadDataTask.resume()

    group.leave()

    group.notify(queue: .main) {

        completion(appsFromItunes)


    }

}
```

Yes, I understand that I have incomplete error handling. I haven't gotten that far. Also, Payload is just a type alias for [String:AnyObject]

Anyway, what this function is suppose to do is create a dataTask with a url that I already have as a string, parse the resulting data and call the escaping closure. Then I am using a DispatchGroup to make sure the dataTask finishes before calling the escaping closure with the appsFromItunes array which should now be populated.

The goal of all this is to retrieve from the url a list of the top apps on iTunes.

Now, this works when I run my project with this in my viewDidLoad:

```
    DataManager.getTopAppsFromItunesNativeParse { (apps) in
        print("this is apps \(apps)")
    }
```

This prints out a large array with the names of the top apps on iTunes.
But, when in my project, I segue to a different view controller, with the same call to getTopAppsFromItunesNativeParse, in its viewDidLoad, the "apps" array is always empty.

I have tried a few different things, such as changing the function to where I have to pass in a url session, but everything I have tried has just felt like a stab in the dark and even if one of my attempts had worked, I am not sure I would be able to explain why. And that is what is really bugging me. I could probably get this to work by passing the data needed in prepareForSegue, but I really want to know why it doesn't work this way.

EDIT: This question has been answered. See comments.

Comment: when calling the function from outside of `DataManager`, are you still setting `DataManager.topAppURL`?  It looks like nothing would happen if that string is empty.

Comment: The group.leave needs to be inside the datatask closure.

Comment: Paulw11 you were exactly right. I needed to move group.leave to inside the dataTask closure. Obviously I do not know enough about dipatchGroups and dataTask construction. Thank you.